# How to convert "uint" type into "string" type in Golang?

Tags: go

I'm working on a piece of code that returns uint data type. I need to convert uint datatype into string for further processing.

I've already tried strconv package and none of the functions accept uint. Golang Documentation: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types states that uint are platform dependent. Is that the reason we don't have any standard functions for conversion?

```
type Example{
    Id uint    //value 3
    name string
}
```

Need to extract Id into a string.

Expected: "3"
Actual: N/A

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [`strconv.FormatUint()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatUint):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    var n uint = 123
    var s string = strconv.FormatUint(uint64(n), 10)
    fmt.Printf("s=%s\n", s)
}
```

([Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/e5QLSgxD17-))

Comment: Umm.. That's not correct. I tried it. It gives "Cannot use Example.Id type uint as type uint64

Comment: @KaushalShah my fault, you need to convert it to `uint64` explicitly.

Comment: Ah! Your edited answer works. Thank you. But I see this as a workaround. What happens if this code is run on 32 bit machine?

Comment: All builtin types must be available regardless of the architecture.

Comment: The uint64 type is available on all architectures and is guaranteed to have a size greater than or equal to the uint type. The code works the same on all architectures.

Comment: I see. Then follow-up question would be: would using uint64() on 32 bit machine give a value different than what we would get on 64 bit machine?

Comment: No. Math is math. If it gave a different answer, it would be fundamentally broken.